# First Responder hat of the 2016 winter bash

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The "First Responder" hat seems to be broken.

[image: First Responder]

The description of the hat states:

> post a message in chat within ±12 hours of the UTC New Year’s begin that gets starred

However, many users, including me, already have the hat.

Comment: Yeah, almost everybody has this hat.

Comment: The bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To be fair, the hat description

> post a message in chat within ±12 hours of the UTC New Year’s begin that gets starred

does *not* mention *which* New Years…

… and so it was accidentally awarded for New Years 2016 :(

Fixed now, and the hats removed (while we tend to let users keep hats that were only awarded because of bugs, in this case it's too obvious).

Comment: Aw, and I liked my 2017 hat 2 weeks early. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I thought getting the hat meant you had to post a message at the appropriate time or else the universe would vanish in a puff of logic.

Comment: @Gilles Excellent idea, I should've done that instead.

Comment: @David, then maybe you shouldn't have narked. ;)

Comment: They took my hat!