# Winter Bash 2019 bugs with the "glasses with a number on top" hat and the "Philanthropist" hat

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

[As in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288273/278094) it appears you all forgot to change the year on those two hats.

Comment: Came here to say this. Got those both immediately too

Comment: We should have a secret bug hat, rewarded to peopel who spot bugs :D

Answer (score 17):

As the saying goes, time is a construct...

Comment: and time flies when you're having fun ;)

Comment: What happened this time?

Comment: So, now I'm [wearing a hat I don't own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t62e.png). 8) And I don't feel like fixing it (nor can I, as I own zero hats, so the UI for changing my hat is missing).

Comment: I should have [saved a screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339986/303080) or left it alone like @Draco18s, rats! Hopefully I'll have better luck with next year's bugs

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica We typed in 2019 instead of 2020 in a couple places. There isn't really much of a story there.

Comment: What about the issues with people being awarded the hat early?

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica Ostensibly those of us who got it early don't have it any more. The only reason it still displays is because we set it as the active hat (and revoking that might be too complicated). They'd be well within their rights to un-set it, of course, which is why I made the comment, but keep it attached for the giggles.  I've got a screenshot and it fits entirely inside the border, so I could just change my avatar if they did revoke it there too.

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica The hats are triggered by specific actions on specific days. So the hats that were awarded early were for people who happened to fulfill the hat requirements, just on the wrong days.