# I am wearing a hat which I am not supposed to have

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2019

Most of us got "Glasses With A Number On Top" hat by mistake and by default I was wearing it from start but that hat was put back in the suitcase by SE but I am still wearing it:

[image]

It should have been removed.

Comment: [Should I blame caching?](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: @NogShine always blame caching

Answer (score 53, accepted):

So here is what happened:

- As [has been documented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339893/winter-bash-2019-bugs-with-the-glasses-with-a-number-on-top-hat-and-the-phila), two hats were erroneously awarded to a few hundred users
- I removed the hats from the winterbash inventories of all of the users involved, as the users in question did nothing to actually win the hats
- However, there were a few dozen users network-wide who not only won one of the hats involved, but were wearing them
- I think that it would be quite uncouth of me to remove hats from users while the hats were being worn. And then leave them hatless? Or randomly assign them other hats from their inventory (and manually place all of them)? And what if they had no other hats?
- The only satisfactory solution that I could come up with was to allow any user wearing the hats in question to continue to wear them as long as they wanted.

Of course, the moment that any of these users elects to switch hats to something else in their inventory, they wont be able to put these hats back on (until the hats are won back, of course).

So the choice is up to the user what to do.

But let no one accuse me of illicit hat-swiping.

And **that** is why you are still wearing the hat in question.

Comment: If *anyone* is still wondering why Yaakov wears and deserves the *Magical Mystical Wizard's Hat*... :))

Comment: I think you'd be well within your rights to take the hat off my (virtual) head, as I didn't actually earn it, but I'm continuing to wear it because of the amusement inherent in the original bug/mistake and the subsequent fix. 8) Plus, its one of the few hats that actually *fits* on my avatar.