# Show off your hats! (2019 edition)

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2019

We obtained [266K hats](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) this past year's WB 2019 contest, and just like the past two Winter Bashes ([2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305135/show-off-your-hats-2017) and [2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320014/show-off-your-hats-2018-edition)) we showed off our new hats.

We [choose our finest hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%EF%B8%8F-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%EF%B8%8F), used the [positioning controls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/hat-positioning/info) to adjust them, and posted a screenshot as an answer. As was the usual, we had a [Winter Bash 2019 chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101913/tarnish-web-2019-) for tips about finding secret hats and other millinery.

With Winter Bash over no more updates are expected here. At the end of 2020 a different contest is expected, this was (supposed to be) the last year for hats.

Comment: Why is this question being negatively received, while the ones for 2017 and 2018 are positively received?

Comment: I remember those started off with negative scores as well.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog I think many people are still angry over the way Monica was treated and don't feel happy at all

Comment: @RichardsaysReinstateMonica There's many more going wrong with Stack Overflow Inc. beyond _how monica was treated_.

Comment: People share what they have with their compatriots but seldom with those whom are most in need. Is the glass half full or half empty. Better to contribute an improvement than fall into dispare.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  yes, but the way monica was treated is the Ur example

Comment: Glorfindel's answer was not festive enough, it seems.

Comment: Wow! The hat-haters are out in full force this year. There are always downvotes on Winter Bash related posts, but this year it is crazy!

Comment: @X-27wantstoReinstateMonica - Don't let a few downvotes discourage you, it takes five down to cancel one up. So that everyone can participate the question was [enthusiastically reopened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9PbI.jpg) an hour ago. If people aren't walking around IRL in a bad mood, and even if they are, such behaviour isn't to be encouraged here. *Off-topic behavior* is off topic.

Comment: I really can't decide if putting a damper on Winter Bash because of the unpleasant events is called for or not. I do miss Monica's participation, though, and I can see that for her Winter Bash would be bitter. I respect those who want to refrain from having fun in a way that will make those who were injured/left SE feel left out.

Comment: There is not good reason to close this! It is a tradition which has been supported even by employees. If it gets closed again I'm definitely going to cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose thanks, I cast a reopen vote. I don't know why we have to go through this _every year_.

Comment: The [Hat Madders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRWy2.jpg).

Comment: @X-27wantstoReinstateMonica I didn't downvote, but I *did* click the "I Hate Hats" button, because everyone's hard work to earn hats is **permanently erased** on January 2nd!!!

Comment: Not so permanent. **Remember**: A Sportsmanship Badge is earned by: "Upvote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score.". --- Answer in the "[Winter Bash 2019 Knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339896/282094)" and "[Show off your hats! (2019 edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340171/282094)" question and get **95** credits for upvoting everyone else. Getting a silver badge earns an ["Amazing Grace"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339892/282094) hat. A Sportsmanship badge helps your [Candidate Score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252643/282094)

Comment: Why do I feel like some of these pics don’t have hats

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because waffles

Answer (score 79):

## [The Merlin says Reinstate Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/256777)

[image: The Merlin says Reinstate Monica]

Comment: Excellent choice of an avatar... it goes well with that hat :)

Comment: Thank you. Judging from the downvotes, at least three people dislike either the hat or the avatar. Or my posting the combination.

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica If you look closely, there are no answers with no downvotes. It seems some people don't really like Winter Bash the way we do it.

Comment: Where may I create a hat of my own?

Comment: I don't like the hats. If they were imposed or hard to disable, I'd be the downvoter from hell. When I looked at the notification this year, I saw that no hat would be displayed unless I adjusted it to fit and said yes. Someone deserves a hat and/or attaboy for fixing that.

Answer (score 56):

## Hero of Stack Exchange

[image]

Answer (score 40):

#### I didn't think I needed a hat on top of my hat, but...

[image]

Comment: Yo Dawg, I heard you like hats, so I put a hat on your hat so your hat can wear a hat while you're wearing a hat.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, after Winter Bash I'll eat my hat.
[image: Winter Bash 2019 - Secret Hat: Rubber Ducky]

---

[image: Tastes like chicken!]

Answer (score 19):

I Tyrion of house Lannister have returned to give more insights to [my story from last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320551/357396)

You all know I fought in the Battle of Blackwater. But you didn't know how I felt after that blow on my face. I saw the stars!

[image: Image of my profile picture containing Peter Dinklage as Tyrion Lannister with Cosmic Brain hat]

But I have considered myself to be clever and put my efforts to save the King's Landing, plotted against other houses. My allies called me clever.

[image: Image of my profile picture containing Peter Dinklage as Tyrion Lannister with The Merlin hat]

But my nephew Joffrey hated me. He insulted me in his wedding.

[image: Image of my profile picture containing Peter Dinklage as Tyrion Lannister with Just Jesting hat]

This is me and cross bow which I used to kill my own father.

[image: my profile picture containing Peter Dinklage as Tyrion Lannister with Werewolf hunter hat]

There was a threat to my life. I have been to a lot of places. I was a slave with a collar to my neck.

[image: My profile picture containing Peter Dinklage as Tyrion Lannister with Warm Welcome hat]

Me dressed as one of the lords of coast of Essos.

[image: Profile picture containing Peter Dinklage as Tyrion Lannister with It's Amazing hat]

I drink and I know things

[image: Image of my profile picture containing Peter Dinklage as Tyrion Lannister in 007 hat with]

Comment: I love GOT. +1 :)

Answer (score 19):

My Hat

[image]

Answer (score 19):

It's not easy to get a hat that looks good on the default [Gravatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravatar). Also in memory of the [time I was clueless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340037/278094)...

**This is Fine**

[image: This is Fine]

Answer (score 18):

It's nothing special but thanks to the [publicist badge bug fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339664/161554) I earned a couple of gold badges during Winter Bash with zero effort

Sky really is a unicorn at heart

[image]

Comment: Aww.. Its so cute!

Comment: A perfect avatar for that hat.

Answer (score 17):

Whoomp!
[image: There it is]
      <sup><sup><sup>Updated image with modified hat.</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: I don't like Winter Bash, but I love this one!

Answer (score 17):

Just a *[narwhal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narwhal)* with a helmet ... Nothing suspicious

[image: Narwhal]

Cosmic Narwhal

[image: narwhal]

The flying Narwhal!

[image]

Narwhal in disguise..

[image]

Gentleman Narwhal

[image]

This is fine....

[image]

A nice warm fire place

[image]

Comment: about the "nothing suspicious here" narwal with Russian hat, is it an oblique reference to https://phys.org/news/2019-05-russian-whale-espionage-speculations-norway.html ?

Comment: It's not. But maybe it is.. Who knows?

Answer (score 16):

I'd rather remove the glasses, but I guess it's good enough.

[image: Hat used as a muzzle on a snow leopard]

Comment: Now we know who ate Grace Hopper's brain. Yikes.

Answer (score 15):

I am wearing the hat [which I am not supposed to have yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340041/i-am-wearing-a-hat-which-i-am-not-supposed-to-have)

[image]

Comment: Congratulations on being in first place on the Leaderboard.

Comment: @Rob btu might fall now :( not getting rest of the hats

Comment: I've seen stranger things than this, however...

Comment: Number one again!

Answer (score 14):

Here's me, showing off hats I didn't earn.

[image]

If they can recycle, so can I...

Comment: "This is Fine" version is the best!

Comment: This looks awfully familiar... maybe I saw something like it a year ago? XD

Comment: @X-27 not last year. I chose some hats I earned in past bashes,  since that's what the organizers of this WB did.

Answer (score 14):

Dr. Sheldon Cooper thinking of all the ways to win the Nobel Prize for his theory of Quantum Physics:

[image]

After winning the Nobel:

[image]

Getting ready for paintball with Penny:

[image]

Sheldon seeing stars on Earth while Howard was in space:

[image]

Dressed for Halloween:

[image]

Pirate Cooper:

[image]

Comment: Reminds me of the pool-of-balls Leonard was chasing Sheldon in... Bazingah.

Comment: You have the lowest reputation here **and** already have a "[This is Fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%ef%b8%8f-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f/339894#339894)" hat, so I am awarding you the bounty (which excludes you from winning another "This is Fine" hat). As a consolation you may keep the 100 reputation after Winter Bash, the hat would have to be returned.

Answer (score 13):

Training unicorns for the army:

[image: unicorn_army]

The unicorn galaxy I call it Uni-verse:

[image: unicorn_univers]

Mother of unicorns:

[image: unicorn_mother]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Ill gotten gains; 2020 edition]

I was one of a [few dozen or so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340047/313685) people that equipped the Glasses With A Number On Top hat before [the date bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339893/313685) was reported and subsequently fixed.

I continue to wear it both for the amusement factor and the fact that few other hats actually fit on my avatar. And before you complain about the jpeg artifacting: no, there is no lossless version of the image; it dates back over a decade to a time when 100x100 pixel avatars were the norm and was sent to me as a 100x100 pixel jpg.

Comment: That is sweet that even when they went and removed the new year's hat from everyone, you were already wearing it so despite no longer having it you can wear it :)

Comment: @X-27wantstoReinstateMonica And I have the screenshot, so even if they had taken it off, I could fake putting it back on just by updating my avatar.

Answer (score 12):

Cosmic cat

[image]

Answer (score 12):

### I decided to become Whosaysbigcatsdontwearhats once again for Winter Bash!

[image: Puma wearing with Werewolf Hunter]

This has a little of the Wild West feeling for me. Good for a wild cat!

---

---

#### *If you are going to look ridiculous*

[image: Puma wearing Bluefeet]

#### *at least try to be dignified!*

[image: Puma wearing top hat]

---

---

#### So cosy...

[image: Puma with burning log on head]

Answer (score 12):

As soon as I (erroneously) was awarded this hat, I couldn't resist. I've been wearing it ever since.

[image: my avatar wearing the "Glasses With A Number On Top" hat]

Comment: You and me, both. 8)

Answer (score 11):

No more space!

[image]

Comment: UVed to 5... yet [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/313/lifejacket) Lifejacket.

Answer (score 11):

**Captain Dad!**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Trogdor burninating communism]

Comment: Possible reference to *[This star on the warm welcome hat looks like a communist symbol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340512)*.

Answer (score 8):

These new glasses I got an early adopter's copy of are amazing!

They give me ***20:20*** vision!

[image]

In *hindesight* though, it probably would have been more fun to pick them up when they officially launch, but it looks like I will be able to collect them again.

<sup>(yeah I know, bad puns)</sup>

Comment: I also get 12 link-publication badges - from yesterday (with one gold) - SO make pre-Christmas cleaning?

Comment: The fact that you put them on after the bug gave them out and kept wearing them since the hat was recalled makes this especially neat.

Answer (score 8):

Look at these zombie ones:
[image][image][image]

Comment: you should put the photos a little smaller

Comment: If you put an "m" on the end of the image link, it will be automatically show smaller. (An "s" would make it really small)

Comment: @hat thanks I tried and it worked (at least for "s"!)

Comment: Great! They are easier to see now.

Answer (score 8):

**Srid says Reinstate Monica**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

My hat has Grace Hopper amazingness and is perfectly positioned.

[image: Amazing hat]

Answer (score 7):

I can’t decide whether to move forward or turn around. What shall I do?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Just a moose cube with a crossbow. Move along folks, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 5):

It's no [chicken on my head](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/162857/munchkin-chicken-head) but close enough
[image]

Comment: You still managed to pick up the [Duck of Doom](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23228/whats-behind-the-duck-of-doom-card).

Answer (score 5):

Hats usually don't fit my profile picture so well, but Merlin does!

[image: Robotnik is a wizard]

Answer (score 5):

#### I just couldn't resist. Who needs turkey?

[image: A toast with ducky]

Nearly done...

#### AARGH. Ducky's revenge!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Should one wear a hat when it's burning? Or is it my fox power?

[image]

## Agent 007?

[image]

## This hat definitely makes me look like Hokage of [Konoha(Leaf Village)](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Konohagakure), Don't you agree?

[image]

## last but not the least, the sun hat

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe that [Ezran](https://dragonprince.fandom.com/wiki/Ezran) is wearing this Merlin hat beautifully. Even if it's true that is brother, Callum, is the real magician here.

[image: Ezran wearing a Merlin hat]

---

I call myself a fool and I must be one, because I decided to wear this beautiful hat:

[image: A tree wearing a "fool" hat]

Answer (score 4):

It's a secret hat for a secret agent (in my dreams)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm a member of SE since 2018, this is the first time that I'm using hats! So let's begin:

A fool hat:

[image]´

A rubber ducky, yay :D

[image]

The moon looking closely after me:

[image]

And the best for last, here's me with a weird hat with funny eyebrows :p :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have changed my profile picture on account of Christmas.

Actually, a lot of hats suit Santa well!

> The Merlin - Merry Santa

[image]

> The Brainy Santa!

[image]

> Why can't Santa hunt? :P

[image]

> Santa too feels cold, right?

[image]

> The Copter Santa and his friend Doraemon.

It'd easy to deliver presents, right? ;)

[image]
[image]

> Rainbow Santa

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Collage work of my #HATS2019

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I spent 15 minutes in GIMP mocking up what I'd look like with the "This Is Fine" hat.

[image: This is fine]

Scaled down variation

[image: This is also fine]

Bonus: Screwing up transparency.

[image: This is still fine]

Comment: You'll get it in three days :)

Answer (score 3):

My Profile picture from another of our sites:
[image: Profile image screenshot]
<sup><sup><sup>Note: Screenshot overlaid on dark background to show outer planet and star.</sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 3):

After change of [symbol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340579/163529) I am eager to wear this hat. Lovely Winter Bash.

[image]

Puppy on fire.

[image]

All-in-one.

[image]

+2 All are on fire. Hope it's understood .

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Flower pot shaped as a moai head, with a top hat, a monocle and a black mustache]

The top hat fits the face, not the "hair".

[image: Flower pot shaped as a moai head with a yellow mask covering the top part of the face]

I just love getting some sun on my face during winter.

[image: Flower pot shaped as a moai head wearing a miniscule Russian ushanka]

At least this ushanka won't slide over my ears.

[image: the same flower point, but now with the burning logs of wood on its head]

Happy [Sol Invictus day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol_Invictus), or Merry Christmas, as the case may be ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## Hats off just to show off the hat underneath.

[image: prof. balthazar]

Answer (score 3):

Someone on the site called me "regular folks". Well, I'll show them!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### I got bored just wearing a single item of finery so I decided to show my wonderful fashion sense by combining items.

[image]

I couldn't resist the John Lennon look as I'm a Liverpudlian:

[image]

Ready for the New Year's Party:

[image]

The DJ was too formal, so I went with a large earring instead:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Last seen in 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats), Solstice (Where in the world?) hats are [back this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321554/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2019?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C43.9890)!

[image: SJ with sun]

These hats have [so many benefits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321609/395288). :-)

They weren’t available [last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320072/395288). Maybe next year I’ll be able to earn [both versions](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com)!

I can also rock [the amazing Grace Hopper hat](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/amazing-grace):

[image: SJ with Grace Hopper hat]

The J is good for a unicorn ([foot of the rainbow](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/foot-of-the-rainbow)) hat:

[image: SJ with unicorn hat]

And I’ve never thought of myself as a [jester](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/just-jesting), so maybe I’m the fool:
[image]

I don’t know how I got [blue in the face](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339894/395288):

[image: SJ with frog mask and feet]

Answer (score 2):

The hardest hats and the new year hats!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## A perfect day for burning some reputation

[image]