# Are zero and negatively-scored answers eligible for the "This Is Fine" hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

The description for the This Is Fine secret hat says:

> Answer a bountied question and receive an upvote, but not the bounty. Answer must be posted during the bounty period but not necessarily during Winter Bash.

There are two ways to define answers that "receive an upvote":

- The intuitive way: answers with a positive score
- The literal way: answers with at least one upvote, no matter what their final score is

Which definition is used for the hat? Do zero and negatively-scored answers that have received at least one upvote count for the hat?

Normally, I wouldn't ask such a question, and would likely assume the intuitive definition, but there is one other case in the system where the literal definition is used: question authors can't delete their own question if it has a single answer with at least one upvote, [even if it's not positively scored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/377214).

This matters because if the literal definition is used, people can game the hat by finding a random question with a bounty, posting a questionable answer to it, and asking another user to give it an upvote: later downvotes from other users can't prevent awarding the hat.

Comment: It's a secret hat, which means you are not going to get an official answer until the end of Winterbash. The description you are quoting is a speculation, partly based on experiments and partly based on this hat's trigger the last time it appeared on Winterbash.

Comment: @Eran The top of the answer says that only confirmed triggers should be in the answer, so I assumed that this was confirmed too.

Comment: It means confirmed by trial and error, not confirmed by SO staff. Even a confirmed trigger is not necessarily a complete trigger (covering all the cases in which you can earn a given hat)

Comment: you definitely might be on the right track here!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 Hat list ❄️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%ef%b8%8f-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f)

Comment: @Mithical Not a duplicate. This question's top answer is cited as a source to the relevant paragraph's claim, so this can't be a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that zero or negatively scored answers don't qualify.

My answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340692/366373) had a score of -2 and no upvotes. Around the same time that the bounty was awarded it received an upvote, but was still negative. I didn't get the hat. My answer was later upvoted again to 0. I still didn't get the hat.

When it received another upvote just now, though, I got the hat. If the post later has a positive score, the hat is awarded.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180391/4751173) is an answer (found with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1170017))

- on a question with an [active bounty posted December 1st](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51229277/revisions)
- created December 4th
- with zero score
- which received an upvote on [December 9th, 16:37](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12333099/james-olrog?tab=reputation) (the day Winter Bash started)
- where the bounty ended that same day on 23:01 UTC, after the upvote

Its owner does not have any hats, so it seems the answer needs to have a positive score, which is one of the [implicit quality requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/295232). (The other possibility is of course that it *does* qualify, but the author explicitly opted out from hats.)

Comment: You'll be able to confirm if that user opted out from hats or not on Dec 21 (assuming that user will post or vote on that day).