# Winter Bash 2020 hat list  

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Winter Bash 2020 has started and the hats (and masks) are listed below.

As always, there are only two answers: one for the secret hats, and one for the regular hats. The secret hat list will be updated as we learn them.

*Please, only edit the secret hat answer with **definitive and correct triggers**. This is not the place to post guesses.* Winter Bash is a fun event, so secret hat triggers should be put behind spoilers (use the `>!` markup) in order to not to spoil the fun for those users who want to discover the triggers themselves.

If you'd like to discuss Winter Bash, hats or just have a question about it please come over to the [Winter Bash 2020 chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117306/winter-bash-2020).

Please keep the comments here clean. As always, comments are not meant for discussion, conversation, "I just got hat X", etc. use the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117306/winter-bash-2020) for that (comments may be cleaned up without further notice).

Here are the hats from previous years:

- [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 Hat list ❄️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339891)
- [Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319838)
- [Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340)
- [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271)
- [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789)
- [Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245170)
- [Winter Bash 2013 Secret Hats](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/03/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

## Secret hats for Winter Bash 2020

**Note: please do *not* edit in a trigger unless it is confirmed by an employee to be correct.**

---

#### Vexillologist

[image: Vexillologist]

1. Raise a helpful flag.
2. *(not figured out yet)*

**Note:** There was a bug in the hat trigger that resulted in the hat being erroneously awarded to users. All hats awarded prior to 2020-12-16 21:37 (UTC) were revoked and re-awarded only to users who actually qualified for it. See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/117306?m=56450361#56450361) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/117306?m=56456059#56456059).

---

#### Samovar

[image: Samovar]

Self-answer your question and get 2 or more upvotes, where the question also gets 2 or more upvotes; doesn't work on per-site-metas.

(Confirmed by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56491908#56491908))

---

#### Quarantine Hair

[image: Quarantine Hair]

Wear a hat on any site.

It is necessary to actually visit the site and manually apply the hat, you can not simply choose to apply one hat on all sites and be awarded this hat on every site.

---

#### Take This!

[image: Take This!]

Take the tour and get the Informed badge.

---

#### Propel Thyself

[image: Propel Thyself]

Get three other secret hats on one site.

---

#### Cordovan

[image: Cordovan]

Post a comment on a question that, within a day, gets edited by the OP. Tag-only edits do not count.

(Confirmed by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56486561) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56507623#56507623)).

---

#### Balalaika

[image: Balalaika]

*(not figured out yet)*

**Note:** There was a bug in the hat trigger that resulted in the hat being erroneously awarded to users early. All hats awarded prior to 2020-12-17 21:04 (UTC) were revoked and re-awarded only to users who actually qualified for it. See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/117306?m=56467555#56467555) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56468782#56468782).

---

#### Disciple

[image: Disciple]

Follow 8 posts.

**Note:** There was a bug in the hat trigger that resulted in the hat having the same trigger as Balalaika. The trigger was changed. All hats awarded prior to 2020-12-17 21:04 (UTC) were revoked and re-awarded only to users who actually qualified for it. See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/117306?m=56467555#56467555) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56468782#56468782).

---

#### Warm Welcome

[image: Warm Welcome]

Upvote any user's first post.

---

#### Mariachi

[image: Mariachi]

Post a chat message that gets 3 stars.

(Confirmed by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56464341#56464341))

---

#### Movin' on Up

[image: Movin' on Up]

Post an answer that gets accepted but has fewer votes than the other answers. Both the question and the accepted answer need to have a positive score.

(Confirmed by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56474678#56474678) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56474968#56474968))

---

#### Give a Leg Up

[image: Give a Leg Up]

Ask a question that is answered by a new contributor (their first post). The Q and the A must both have a positive score.

(Confirmed by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56559089#56559089))

---

#### This is Fine

[image: This is Fine]

Answer a bountied question but don't receive the bounty, and have a [positive score when](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340757/282094) the calculation script is run. Answer must be posted during the bounty period but not necessarily during Winter Bash. If you answer your own question, have a positive score, and offer the bounty you win this hat when you award the bounty.

(Implicitly confirmed by Catija [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56479588))

---

#### Cruse of Oil

[image: Cruse of Oil]

Ask, answer, or vote on December 18th.

(Confirmed in principle by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/117306?m=56475014#56475014))

---

#### Eliza Doolots

[image: Eliza Doolots]

Earn 2021 rep across the network, excluding association bonus. Hat is awarded on sites where you earn 200+ rep.

---

#### Carnaval

[image: Carnaval]

Edit for six days. Note that tag edits will not count.

(Confirmed by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56506160#56506160) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/117306?m=56514255#56514255))

---

#### Defender of the Unicorn

[image: Defender of the Unicorn]

1. Manually awarded to users who exposed weaknesses in the Hat Dash game. These users are listed under the [White Hat Hall of Fame](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/leaderboard). See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358546/hat-dash-white-hat-hall-of-fame-and-leaderboard-refresh) for more information.
2. Answer 10 questions correctly at https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/unicorn. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358638/can-you-help-a-poor-unicorn-to-find-its-way-back-home) for more information.
3. Also [manually awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358065/hat-display-bug/358561#358561) to balpha.

**Note:** This hat was [created by Yaakov Ellis during Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358546/hat-dash-white-hat-hall-of-fame-and-leaderboard-refresh#comment1197288_358546).

---

#### Right to run fast and jump for joy

Not a hat per se, but the trigger for this is not disclosed. You need to have earned this "right" (and be logged into the Winter Bash site) to be able to access the "game" on that site. That you've gained the "right" is announced in the Winter Bash drop-down menu on the top bar, just as earning any other hat.

This privilege is earned by wearing the Social Distancing hat.

(Implicitly confirmed by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357996))

---

Comment: I already got two of these, what the heck?

Comment: @DonThousand being secret doesn't mean it's hard to get. Sometimes it's easy but the challenge is figuring out what the trigger was. 

Comment: Also, to be completely honest, some hats are secret because we like the triggers but want to minimize the number of people doing those actions.

Comment: Warm welcome may be the same as [last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339894/763699) (Sorry, I had to use a link because I don't know how you put spoilers in comments)

Comment: The trigger for Vexillologist seems to be incorrect. I got in on SO without doing what this answer mentions.

Comment: I think Vexillologist relates to a mod acting (positively) on your post. I received after a diamond mod approved pair of tag edits. Seems consistent with both @yagmoth555's proposal and others' experiences.

Comment: I got Vexillogist and I definitely did not contact a CM. Probably one of my flags was marked as helpful.

Comment: I've got Vexillologist. I think because I've set a flag on somebody's question

Comment: got Vexillologist without raising helpful flag on stackoverflow

Comment: @KodosJohnson It's one of the triggers. Maybe getting an edit approved is another one. When was the last time you raised a helpful flag? It also may have been a ***bug*** as I just suddenly earned "social distancing" on both StackApps and AskUbuntu without ever visiting either of those sites since days ago.

Comment: @ppwater But it could also be for earning your first badge. You should try on a different site, and this time don't do the tour.

Comment: @user1271772 Oh, you mean `Take This!` Well, just got the priv to review suggested edit, then got a reviewer badge, no hat (oh, just noticed you said **first**. sorry nvm)

Comment: @ppwater please combine your 3 comments that were all within 43 seconds of each other, into one comment. And by the way, you got the "informed" badge on the site where you got the Take This hat.

Comment: I got a **Take This** on Medial Sciences after raising a spam flag, possibly the one that killed the post.

Comment: `Take This` is associated to earning a new badge, not to the association bonus (and not to rep. change).

Comment: I just got Cordovan. It seems to be related to having an answer upvoted, or perhaps (first?) answer upvoted and accepted,

Comment: Suspicion on the 'Right to run fast and jump for joy': https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358001/369802

Comment: You have to wear a social distancing hat to earn the right to play Hat Dash.

Comment: The balalaika and the Desciple badge are related to comments. Most likely having an upvoted comment

Comment: I've got `Propel Thyself` (confirmed)

Comment: I think 1 suffices @PeterHaddad, but the question at which you place the comment also plays some sort of role.

Comment: *This Is Fine* is possibly from 2015 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/789426

Comment: I wonder if balalaika is related to a number of comments on a post. I just got it after posting 5 comments on the same thread

Comment: Cordovan is also probably related to the comments. I commented on a post, the OP replied and edited the post, and I got it.

Comment: I just got Balalaika and Disciple at once right after answering a question on Stack Overflow that I had already posted a comment on. Not sure if that was the trigger.

Comment: I got Balalaika and Disciple after a long comment discussion. The question was edited during the discussion, so maybe it's related to comments/edits?

Comment: I already got the informed badge, but I have not got the `Take This` hats?? Do you get it if you already have the badge?

Comment: Got cordova hat to a question asked today.  First wrote a comment responded to by OP mentioning me, and then wrote a first answer.

Comment: Wait, just took a bit to get the hat :)

Comment: Idk if somebody already pointed that out but I assume you get balalaika if someone upvotes your comment and disciple when you earn a badge

Comment: @Marybnq I've got the Disciple hat even though I haven't earned any badges today.

Comment: I got Balalaika and Disciple, but it seems they were both immediately after I commented, so did ***not*** have anything to do with upvoting of the comments. The comment still doesn't have an upvote. I tagged a user and gave a link to a chat room in the comment. I also edited the question by adding one tag, 1 hour before the comment.

Comment: To get Movin' on Up, according to what I saw you need to answer a question and your answer should be marked as correct but it should have less votes compared to another answer. Example https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster (answer with 3 upvotes & marked as correct but other answerer has 6 upvotes)

Comment: @PeterHaddad Your experiment on my answer proves this point.

Comment: I have Vexillologist on a large number of sites where my only interaction recently is flagging; por exemplo, [pt.so] (I don't speak Portuguese either, but you should be able to guess what the labels mean, or compare to your own flagging history on a site where they are in English. In case you are wondering how I find all this spam, I'm active in [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org).) A bit baffled that this hat is now back to *"(not figured out yet)"* It's clearly not just spam flags; the PT one was [abusive.](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/280905)

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 Same here, I also just got Cordovan like that. I added a comment about how to improve a question and then OP did an edited (the question got closed anyway though).

Comment: Got Balalaika and Disciple at the same time. I think you need to post a certain number of comments on the site, not necessarily on the same question; maybe it’s related to frequency of comments.

Comment: I just got the curse of oil, but I have no idea how. After someone added the curse of oil to the answer here. I saw where they gained it, created an account in that stackexchange site to check how they got it, then went back to stackoverflow and got it there. It has nothing to do with answering or asking so not really sure

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I just got Curse of Oil as well - on two related sites about 5 minutes apart

Comment: I also received Curse of Oil and I think all I did was upvote a new question on that site.

Comment: Yup, I just confirmed that Cruse of Oil is earned on a site simply by upvoting a question. I don't know if the age of the question matters, but it wasn't from a brand-new user, and it wasn't their first question, although it was fairly new. It seems to be a brand-new hat, just unlocked today.

Comment: This may shed light: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_of_the_cruse_of_oil - a single light must be lit continuously and burn from evening to morning#

Comment: I also earned the Cruse of oil for upvoting an older question (posted Nov 5), so it seems it does not have to be a new question.

Comment: Since Cruse of Oil lasted for eight days, maybe "vote within 8 days until christmas"? From 17th to 24th December at midnight. I earned it by upvoting no matter if it was a question or an answer, doesn't matter the votes it had, and I did that too yesterday but didn't earn the hat - that is why I think it is "8 days until christmas".

Comment: @RafaelTavares 18 December is the last day of Hanukkah. (And yes, it's already 18 December in some parts of the world)

Comment: also, I am not getting the Warm Welcome despite having upvoted several first posts on different stacks

Comment: @Glorfindel the first time I earned the hat I upvoted a post at 2020-12-17 10:24:08Z. It wasn't the 18th anywhere then I think.

Comment: @Glorfindel Tested the trigger for `Cruse of Oil` on several accounts in different combinations: It's awarded when an upvote is locked on a question or answer (never mind if it's old or new or has an accepted answer/is accepted) - Can you confirm that behaviour?

Comment: I am pretty sure the trigger for Mariachi is to get 3 stars on chat.

Comment: @demonplus I got Vexologist for I site I moderate, so it wasn't for raising flags.

Comment: I got mariachi after a chat message was starred three or more times.

Comment: Got Vexillologist on two sites after SD autoflagged for me. It's either flagging or spam flags specifically. Possibly handling flags for mods

Comment: Just got curse of oil by UV old question (2018) indeed... my guess is what? at least 6 months?

Comment: @Glorfindel So Cruse of Oil is for upvoting a question or answer on the last day of Hanukkah (Dec. 18)?

Comment: I think the trigger for "Cruse of Oil" is simply voting on questions on the last day of Hanukkah (by UTC, perhaps, as it's not sundown in my local timezone). I've gotten it for both up- and down-votes, the score of the question doesn't seem to matter, nor does the age since I've got it for voting on new questions while other got it for voting on old questions. You don't get it right away, so I think the vote needs to be locked in

Comment: @Zoe - Hmmm. I *did* handle a spam flag recently. We actually don't get a lot of those, so it was memorable.

Comment: I've gotten a couple of "Cruse of Oil" hats, so I did some testing. I've upvoted Qs and As, together and separately. It appears that upvotes on Qs of any age get the hat, since I got it on a Q asked yesterday. Tomorrow is the end of Hanukkah locally and it's still Dec 17 UTC, so I don't think it has anything to do with that. I didn't earn it yesterday, so it can't just be "during Hanukkah", either.

Comment: @computercarguy The last night of Hanukkah starts at sundown on December 17th (days on the Jewish calendar go from sundown to sundown), so if the requirement is for it to be the last night of Hanukkah, that requirement would be met _sometime_ today

Comment: @divibisan, ok, thanks. I was just trying to research that. So the hat is potentially for upvoting a Q on the last night/full day of Hanukkah to coincide with the last time you refill the menorah?

Comment: @computercarguy It goes from downvotes too – I think it's just any votes. Is there any way to check exactly when you got the hat? If we knew when people started getting the hat, then we could figure out the exact trigger. If the hat starts at a single time for the whole world, I'd guess that sundown in Jerusalem would make sense. That would be 4:38 IST = 2:38pm UTC = 9:38 EST = 6:38 PST

Comment: @divibisan, I have no way to tell when it started, since I didn't start looking at SE/SO until after 8:30AM PST. I tested the DV to confirm, and yes, it does appear that voting either way on a Q earns the hat.

Comment: I think Disciple has something to do with commenting. I left 3 comments today on Meta (in UTC, of course) and 5+ on Astronomy, and got both Cruse of Oil and Disciple

Comment: I got the badge on SO after flagging spam. Had NAA flags approved before that, which didn't trigger the hat. Can confirm it's related to spam, but not entirely sure on the details.

Comment: I just got disciple and I'm pretty sure the only things I did were commenting under one answer and one question (different posts).

Comment: I also got Balalaika at the same time.

Comment: I am wondering if the knot on the vexillologist might be a clue on how it is earned? Something like the name of that specific knot would be a clue?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I think that's just what the vexillologist flag looks like (a vexillologist is apparently someone who studies flags)

Comment: @user Oh, you're totally right, indeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Federation_of_Vexillological_Associations

Comment: I confirmed on a fresh site that you get Cruse of Oil by upvoting an answer and a comment on the same question. Can a mod confirm please?

Comment: I got Cruse of Oil on Graphic Design where pretty much my only interaction is flagging as spam.

Comment: I got Cordovan on Russian Language, where pretty much my only recent interaction is leaving a comment. The comment was upvoted, so I guess that's it. (Also, however, I edited the comment once. That would be my second guess.)

Comment: Vexillologist flag could be triggered either on a comment flag or question edit with custom edit message. Likely the former. Anyone confirm?

Comment: @tripleee Likewise on History, and I didn't do anything else at that time.

Comment: I got Cruse of Oil on Super User. The only things I did there the same day as I got the hat were: (1) edited and commented on an answer, (2) downvoted and flagged an answer and (3) reviewed a few suggested edits.

Comment: I also got Vexillologist on Super User, also for doing only those three actions.

Comment: It's not (1) because I did that on Stack Overflow as well and didn't get any of those hats there.

Comment: I just earned Cruse of Oil on Stack Overflow. The only thing I did recently there that I also did on Super User was that I downvoted an answer, so Cruse of Oil probably has something to do with voting. I haven't earned Vexillologist on Stack Overflow though, so Vexillologist probably has something to do with flagging.

Comment: I just earned Cruse of Oil on Meta Stack Exchange after upvoting a bug report. I haven't downvoted anything on Meta today and I haven't upvoted anything on Super User today, so it seems like Cruse of Oil has something to do with voting in general.

Comment: I earned Cruse of Oil on Meta for upvoting swag announcement. That is the only action I performed there at all (other than just browsing obvs)

Comment: I just tried on 2 sites to upvote a question and answer - both gave me the cruse of oil hat. So the trigger is definitely to vote on something, likely it's during a specific time, likely to be on the last day of Hannukah I suppose.

Comment: Earned Cruse of Oil after upvoting a question and answer on SO.

Comment: I just earned Cordovan on Meta Stack Exchange. The only thing I can think of that I did here and not on any other sites was that I voted to close a question as a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps you get Cruse of Oil just by visiting a site multiple times in a day. I got it just now on Meta SE and I haven't interacted here at all in the past day, but I have visited it multiple times.

Comment: I'm quite sure Vexillologist is awarded for having a flag marked helpful. I just got it on Stack Overflow when I was away from the site, and the only thing that happened during the time I was away was that a flag I had raised got marked helpful. This is also consistent with how I earned it on Super User.

Comment: Earned Cruse of Oil on Puzzling after 1. Upvoting a question and 2. Answering that question within 5 minutes of it being asked. 3. That answer was upvoted but not yet marked correct.

Comment: There is a theory that Cordovan is about commenting. I guess we'll see

Comment: I just did a bit of review-queue stuff and deleted a post by a new user, and I was re-awarded Vexillologist in case that's a clue for anyone.  I did not flag anything.

Comment: I think Cruse of Oil is if you view someone's profile.

Comment: I think @DonaldDuck is right, Vexillologist is awarded for raising a flag that's marked as helpful.

Comment: Got Balalaika after posting one more comment. Not upvoted, Previous comments were on different questions.

Comment: I have just recieved Vexilologist after a helpfull "spam" flag on Code Review. I had got it due to the bug (after a helpfull flag(?)) on Meta Stack Exchange and my hat was removed, but later I have got it again (helpful "spam" flag(?)).
+ Earned hat after a helpful "Very low quality" flag.

Comment: I wonder if "Give a Leg Up" involves upvoting someone else's answer on a question that you answered.

Comment: There is a Eliza Doolots hat!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath No, I tried to test your hypothesis by visiting someone's profile on Tex-Latex which is the only site where I don't have Cruse of Oil, and I still don't have it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Cruse of Oil was date specific (Dec 18 anywhere in the world). It's too late to get it now. During the correct date it was possible to get it by voting, asking a question or posting an answer.

Comment: I seem to have earned Balalaika for checking out someone else's hats on a specific site.

Comment: I just got awarded the 'Carnaval' hat after an edit of mine was approved (pretty much directly) that I made to a question that my answer to had been accepted before. Not sure which parts are relevant for getting the hat though...

Comment: I just got Balalaika on Stack Overflow even though I haven't done anything there today. Other users seem to think it has something to do with comments, so maybe a comment I posted yesterday got upvoted.

Comment: A new guess for Cruse of oil: to receive the hat, you must have been given one of the bugged hats (Balalaika or Disciple) but then had it revoked (as it happens, on Dec 18, the last day of Hannukah).

Comment: I got Cruse of Oil for a group where I just signed up and upvoted a question. I don't have any other actions on this group, so I assume it has to do with upvoting a question. The answer I upvoted was also the user's first post and was not the accepted answer, but my vote made it the highest repped vote.

Comment: I got Balalaika on Super User where my only recent activity other than flagging spam is leaving a few comments on a single question, one of which was upvoted. (Ironically, [this.](https://superuser.com/questions/1610851/issues-using-ffmpeg-and-easy-screen-please-help-see-logs#comment2455923_1610851))

Comment: movin` on up, according to this, needs to be on a positive votes question, but that was not the case here .Accepted as fewer votes than another answer, but question had 0 votes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423246/custom-validation-service-for-null-property/65423348?noredirect=1#comment115665442_65423348

Comment: I got Balalaika on Academia.  My only activites there since Dec 16 were three comments (on three different questions) with 0,1,2 upvotes.  The most recent one was 2 days before the Balalaika was awarded.  Maybe it took that long to get the 2nd upvote?  Another possibility to look at: the question where I have the 2-upvote comment was just closed at about the time I got the balalaika.

Comment: Received Vexillologist for successfully flagging any post (irrespective of type of flag e.g. spam or not an answer etc.).

Comment: Vexillologist has to be having a flag marked helpful. The times match exactly for the when I've got it. Where are employees supposed to be confirming the guesses?

Comment: Vexillologist  is when you've flagged a post, I got mine right after flagging a new post.

Comment: Vexillologist has [two triggers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56477737#56477737), we are sure that one is an accepted flag; the second isn't confirmed.

Comment: I got my fourth balalaika.  My guess for this ... make a comment, upvoted, on a question later closed.  Maybe 2 upvotes are required, but not more.

Comment: if the balalaika and cordovan are associated with comments, then perhaps the balalaika is given for the comment under the answer, which will be changed

Comment: I believe I got balalaika after posting 5 comments on the same thread (the question/ answer was old)

Comment: I got another balalaika.  I have one comment in each of three different threads (since Dec 20), but none of the questions has been closed.

Answer (score 57):

## Regular hats for Winter Bash 2020

#### Social Distancing (Main)

[image: Social Distancing (Main)]

Visit any question page on any main site (including Meta Stack Exchange). Visits through the mobile apps, and visits to tag pages (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and review queues count as well.

---

#### Social Distancing (Meta)

[image: Social Distancing (Meta)]

Visit any question page on any meta site (including Meta Stack Exchange). Visits through the mobile apps, and visits to tag pages (e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/discussion) and review queues count as well.

---

#### TikTop

[image: TikTop]

Ask a question that gets answered fast.
Ask a question that gets an answer in under 5 minutes. Both the question and answer must have a positive score.

---

#### Soapbox

[image: Soapbox]

Start a meta discussion.
Ask a question with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag on a meta site that gets a score of 2 or more and receives 2 or more answers.

---

#### Edward

[image: Edward]

Ask a positively-received question on five different days (get the Curious badge).
Each day during a 5-day period, ask a positively scored question and have no negatively scored, closed or deleted questions.

---

#### Hanafuda

[image: Hanafuda]

5 posts with a positive score.
Post 5 questions or answers during Winter Bash that receive a positive score.

---

#### Backlog

[image: Backlog]

Answer an old question with no answers.
Answer a question from 2019 or earlier that does not have any answers. Both question and answer must have a positive score.

**Note:** Question cannot have any [deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358910/backlog-hat-not-awarded-after-requirements-met/358912#comment1198389_358912).

---

#### Snaphat

[image: Snaphat]

Answer in 30 minutes, +3 and accepted.
Answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked. Answer must have a score of 3 or more, and the question asker must accept it.

---

#### Rep Hunter

[image: Rep Hunter]

10 answers in 1 day with positive score.
Post 10 answers on the same day. All answers must have a positive score.

---

#### Kitsune

[image: Kitsune]

Vote to reopen and answer a question.
Vote to reopen a question, and answer it when it gets reopened. Both actions must occur during Winter Bash.

---

#### I Wish to Subscribe

[image: I Wish to Subscribe]

Upvote 3 feature requests on MSE.
Upvote 3 questions with the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag on Meta Stack Exchange.

---

#### Bûche de Noël

[image: Bûche de Noël]

Ask, answer, or vote on December 25th.
Ask, answer, or vote ±12h from Dec 25, 0:00 UTC

**Note:** Doesn't award hats for activity on per-child metas or Stack Overflow Teams.

---

#### Where in the World?

[image: Where in the World?]

Post or vote on Dec 21.
Ask, answer, or vote ±12h from Dec 21, 0:00 UTC. This hat comes in two versions, but you can only get one.

---

#### Where in the World?

[image: Where in the World?]

Post or vote on Dec 21.
Ask, answer, or vote ±12h from Dec 21, 0:00 UTC. This hat comes in two versions, but you can only get one.

---

#### Happy New Year

[image: Happy New Year]

Chat on Jan 1.
Post a message in chat ±12h from Jan 1, 0:00 UTC. Message must be starred.

---

#### Milliner

[image: Milliner]

Collect 11 hats.
Collect 11 hats on a specific site.

---

#### Bouncer

[image: Bouncer]

3 successful close vote reviews.
Make 3 reviews in the close votes queue that ultimately get handled the way you recommended, and at least one other reviewer took the same action as you.

---

#### Doorman

[image: Doorman]

3 successful reopen vote reviews.
Make 3 reviews in the reopen votes queue that ultimately get handled the way you recommended, and if voting to Leave Closed at least one other reviewer took the same action as you.

---

#### Chimney Sweep

[image: Chimney Sweep]

3 successful suggested edit reviews.
Make 3 reviews in the suggested edits queue that ultimately get handled the way you recommended.

**Note:** Reviewing directly from the post page also counts.

---

#### Wa-boushi

[image: Wa-boushi]

Earn the Guru badge.
Post an answer that gets accepted and has a score of 40 or more (earn the Guru badge).

---

#### Carmen

[image: Carmen]

Suggested edit approved.
Suggest one or more edits that get approved during Winter Bash. Tag Wiki excerpts count, which is helpful for some privileged users.

---

#### Gimme Space

[image: Gimme Space]

Join new community.
Join a Stack Exchange community that you have never participated in.

---

#### Flashlight

[image: Flashlight]

Try Dark Mode.
Have Dark Mode enabled and visit a page on Stack Overflow in English, Japanese, Portuguese, Russian, or Spanish.

---

#### Comin' Up Roses

[image: Comin' Up Roses]

Ask a +5 question with 5 answers.
Ask a question with a score of 5 and above that receives at least 5 answers. All answers must have a positive score.

---

#### Matryoshka

[image: Matryoshka]

10 successful close or reopen votes.
Vote to close or reopen 10 questions that ultimately get closed or reopened

---

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange counts as both a main site *and* a meta site for the purposes of the "Social Distancing" hats, so visiting a question there will earn you both hats.

Comment: How are you meant to earn the Carmen hat if you have already pass the "suggested edit" rep threshold?

Comment: @Lankymart Suggest some tag edits

Comment: @Lankymart join a site where you don't have the privilege.

Comment: @Lankymart - Who says everyone is "meant to" earn every hat?

Comment: **Warning**: Apparently, for the "Backlog" hat, the question needs to be at least one year old

Comment: Is it just me, or does the "Social Distancing" one look like a diaper to anyone else? I know it's supposed to be a surgical style mask, but it kind of looks like a full diaper instead. Lol.

Comment: @computercarguy Definitively not just you x)

Comment: Does Flashlight actually work? I switched to Dark Mode on Stack Overflow, but no hat...

Comment: @JW8, yes, it does. My very first hat this year was Flashlight.

Comment: @computercarguy, so do the masks in real life, especially when you find them littering the streets.

Comment: @computercarguy, by my read of the Flashlight requirements, I should be able to turn Dark Mode on in settings, and get the hat by visitnig any page. Does that match your experience? (Still no hat...)

Comment: @JW8, I already had dark mode turned on, probably from as soon as it was available, so as soon as I got onto SE/SO I got that hat instantly and without having to do anything else. Sorry I can't be of help there.

Comment: @computercarguy, figured it out - my profile actually had the setting set to "system preference", once i flipped it to "dark mode", i got the hat. Thanks!

Comment: i have 11 hats, but I have not gotten milliner??

Comment: @KetZoomer Milliner is granted after you collect 11 hats on the same site. While you have 11 hats over all, you don't yet have 11 hats in any specific site.

Comment: thank makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I asked a question yesterday and it got +20 and 5 answers with +3 or more. For the Coming Up Roses hat, do all of the answers need to be +1, not just 5? Can I game the hat by upvoting them myself?

Comment: What is going on with the Where in the world hat(s)? I got one on two sites, got the second one on both sites, lost both on both sites and got one again on both sites.

Comment: @Willeke There was a bug in the trigger that awarded both hats (sun and moon), which was fixed. So you'd see both of them awarded, reverted, and then the right one awarded.

Comment: I understood I got the second one wrongly, as it states you can only earn one. But on the other hand, I feel it is wrong to award and then remove hats. If a bug hands out hats, that is it. Let the people who were so lucky keep them.

Comment: @BelovedFool - I have answers in on two old posts, one 3 months, the other 15 months. No Backlog hat yet, though I did get the badge for the 3 month as it received its first upvote. At the moment I can only guess the older one also needs a + vote for the hat. (I thought it was a darn good answer too ;)

Comment: Is "Sun/Moon" based on user ID? Sun : odd, Moon: even I have been trying to get Moon which has been incorrectly awarded to me in the beginning but was not able to across SE sites.

Comment: @Mr.T AFAIK, they are based on the timezone you're posting from

Comment: That was my initial thought, too. But this would not guarantee that you get only one version. One could use a proxy in another country and get both versions.

Comment: @Mr.T Unless the hat's trigger checks if you already have one of the two and won't grant you the other one after you already got the first one

Comment: My theory can easily be discarded by one user who does not adhere to the rule. I just checked 10. Do you want to write a script for all other users? Don't forget to short-circuit it if you found the first counter-example :)

Comment: @Mr.T it may be simpler than that - I have an even userId on SO and an odd userId on MSE but have the sun hat on both

Comment: Well, there you have your counterexample.Comes as a surprise to me that user IDs are not consistent across SE sites.

Comment: I wish to subscribe doesn't seem to trigger for me for some reason.

Comment: @computercarguy Definitely, I would say that.

Comment: For Matryoshka hat, can it be all CVs or RVs or does it have to be some sort of ratio between them? Like 5 CVs and 5 RVs.

Comment: Ugh, too bad I don't ask too many questions anymore. My Edward avatar needs an Edward hat!

Comment: I wonder if the Matryoshka hat is not available if you are a mod on the site you cast your re-open and close votes. Or whether they have to be done within a given time period. (Not willing to experiment much as it would disturb the site to much.)