# Why is Warm Welcome secret?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Why is Warm Welcome a secret hat?

It's kinda obvious for some people how to get Warm Welcome:

> just upvote a newbie

Yet why is it secret when almost everyone knows the trigger?
Edit: I don't get the downvotes.

Comment: In addition to what was written below - we have in the past (and maybe this year as well) used old hats but given then new triggers. Just saying.

Comment: I think that you got the downvotes because of the tone and the way that you wrote the question. Just speculation... I actually don't know what exactly they took issue with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's obvious *if you participated in Winter Bash before* and read the discussions or wrap-up blog post. We have a lot of new users (new to the network or new to Winter Bash) who don't know the trigger and like to find out themselves. So thanks for putting the trigger behind a spoiler!

Answer (score 15):

Not everyone is a fanatic, veteran hat-hunter. There are new users that won't have found the trigger in previous years.

The trigger for this one being secret might have something to do with some triggers being secret because [SE wants to minimize the people performing that action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357915/winter-bash-2020-hat-list#comment1195707_357917). Having people

> massively upvote new user posts

regardless of quality can be harmful to moderation, so making it secret for that reason makes sense.