# Is the "Take This!" hat (⚔️) a toy sword?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2020

I am particularly fond of the "Take This!" hat as it fits my avatar quite well (at least in my opinion), but I was wondering what kind of sword it is supposed to be?

Given the festive vibe of Winter Bash I suppose it is a toy sword of some sort that the "little ones" get. On the other hand looking at the cross-guard it can be even Batman's sword as well. (In that case I might want to replace the cat on my avatar to [Batcat](https://youtu.be/NLu0uhx_r5g).)

What are your thoughts on that?

For reference:

[image]

Comment: Full list of hats [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357915/winter-bash-2020-hat-list).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is quite clearly the [Master Sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_of_The_Legend_of_Zelda#Master_Sword) from the *The Legend of Zelda* series.

The tagline is a reference to the phrase ["It's dangerous to go alone! Take this."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_dangerous_to_go_alone!), which is used to introduce the sword in the 1986 NES version of the game.

Comment: To be fair, it didn't introduce the "Master Sword" but just a generic sword. The "Master Sword" isn't even mentioned directly till the SNES game "Link to the Past", and then retconed so that the "Magic Sword" in Zelda 1 is considered to be the "Master" Sword. But yep, that is the source of the quote.

Comment: Master posting it and you can have upvote.