# Are hat requirements posted after the event?

Tags: support, winter-bash, secret-hats

This is my first Winter Bash event. is it possible to find a list of requirements for *all* Winter Bash hats after the event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're posted during the event and retained afterward (post isn't deleted) - for the secret hats, the requirements are posted as and when they're officially confirmed.

[Winter Bash 2020 hat list 👒 🎩](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357915/winter-bash-2020-hat-list)

Comment: Darn I can't accept the answer for 11 minutes.

Comment: Make coffee..  In my world, 11 minutes is long enough for three coffees.