# Numbers, numbers, hats and numbers everywhere

Tags: discussion, statistics, winter-bash-2020

Where can we see **current** (live) statistics for the 2020 hat season?

I am aware of the Leaderboard but I'm interested in specific statistics of which hats are common, rare, and what are the site-specific differences.

Maybe [CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/) Meta already has a data visualization available?

In comments people have asked what kind of detail level I want to see:

- Minimum: Hat distribution for all SE users
- Happiness: Subgroup analysis for participating SE sites
- To die for: Subgroup analysis over time (16 Dec - 04 Jan) AND in comparison to previous years (where comparable)

I want to be able to view specific details about a specific hat (such as the [Carnaval](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/carnaval) hat) and its current distribution across our sites.

Comment: You can kinda tell which hats are the most rare by looking at the user leaderboards - the rarest hats are listed first, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think the unusual hats are listed first.

Comment: Common, I am a scientist. I want hard facts about the distribution of the Carnaval hat across sites. This is serious.

Comment: We don't keep a running total of all hats available anywhere. At the end, we release some data about how many hats were released and we may be able to post additional data here but that likely won't happen until January.

Comment: I will patiently wait. [D'oh. "C'mon."]

Comment: Adding the information from [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358493/numbers-numbers-hats-and-numbers-everywhere#comment1197128_358493) might clairify the exactness of the answer you would prefer - possibly from SEDE, or past years statistics interpolated over this year's; maybe someone will even scrape the Leaderboard and create a chart.

Answer (score 4):

The [/stats page](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/stats) is now updated for this year's event. I'll see about the feasibility of making anonymized hat data available for data-hounds to feast on (basically: what hats were earned per anonymized user, per site, and when).

We do not have data from previous years easily accessible.

What would you do with the data if provided?

Comment: Pure curiosity about how people behave differently on the various SE sites. The original question had an ironic tone that other people edited out because I know this is not the most important problem in the world. But I feel strangely attracted to these kinds of data representations.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate [question on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361045/3648282) with [slightly more detailed comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361045/can-i-find-out-how-many-times-a-particular-hat-has-been-awarded#comment542302_361045) than what was [offered by Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358493/numbers-numbers-hats-and-numbers-everywhere#comment1197124_358493):

> "I don't know about any way of finding out how many people have a certain hat, but you can find out what hat is the rarest on the network-wide leaderboard. The hats of each user there are ordered with the rarest first, so it's very likely that the first hat in the list of the #1 user's hats is the rarest (in this case "Waffles"). – Donald Duck Dec 23 '17 at 20:24"

[Network Leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network):
[image: Current Leaders]

Comparing those two, taking the next few into account, and consulting [this year's Hat List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357915/winter-bash-2020-hat-list), it looks like [Rep Hunter](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/rep-hunter) is the rarest.

That answers your first question directly, explains how to figure out your second answer, and leaves your third question for *Statistics Day* (next year). An exact answer can only be offered when all the data is available, at the end of Winter Bash.

Here is the [Winter Bash 2019](https://web.archive.org/web/20200106164615/https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/stats) statistics webpage; it probably falls a little short of your minimum requirements. Note that Wayback is missing the 2018 webpage, but some of the prior years are available.

Now that this year's Winter Bash has ended the statistics that Stack Exchange offers is [available here](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/stats)  and [has been archived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU66Y.png) on [Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20200106164615/https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/stats).