# At what point should someone post a new question instead of replying to the original feature announcement?

Tags: discussion, announcements

Usually when a new feature is added to the network, an announcement post is created and users are urged to reply to the announcement with any bug reports or possible enhancement requests.

However, I have noticed that after a while activity on the original post goes down, and I'm not sure if I should still reply to the original or create a new post. Is there some time after the original announcement when posting a new question is acceptable? Perhaps 6 - 8 weeks? On the other hand, maybe the announcement post can be closed to signal that separate posts are preferred.

Comment: Sometimes the announcement has instructions how long answers as bugs are welcome. In the cases I've see it was more like 6 to 8 days, so if you stick to 6 to 8 weeks you should be fine.

Comment: On more recent announcement posts, I've seen staff post an explicit time (two weeks or one month) after which issues and requests should be posted as new questions. But this doesn't always happen, and this is useful to know especially when one has something to report during this in-between time when the announcement was recently made but it's not "old".

Comment: I personally have a major distaste for *repost because forgotten* reports. At least I would hope such reposts bring a new insight on the table that demonstrates how the bug is affecting a large group of users.

Comment: @rene "...bring a new insight on the table" funnily enough my question was prompted by a new post about table support haha. Seriously though, do you say that even considering the original bug report was an answer instead of a question which can be more easily tracked?

Comment: I guessed the table had something to do with it. I think making a question for an FR that got posted as an answer after 6 to 8 weeks should be fine, given the original OP of the answer is pinged to promote their answer to a question. But that is more courtesy then anything else.

Comment: @rene Regarding your first comment on the post: while I agree with that, I think that that's hard to do when the original post already had a *lot* of insight and research, that there just isn't much more to add because it already contains a lot of arguments.

Comment: A search for the terms "[\[announcement\] "new question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bannouncements%5D+%22new+question%22) " turns up several examples to sift through; along with a lot of cruft. One would need to compile the general flow of several questions to determine an appropriate answer. Note that there's a [Samovar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917/282094) hat for answering your own question (with sufficient upvotes); along with other applicable hats, for other triggers.