# Why didn't I get the Edward hat - Winter Bash?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Why am I not getting the [Edward hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357915/winter-bash-2020-hat-list/357916#357916) on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) (ELL)?

I already asked seven positive scored question on seven different days, and I already earned the [Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/67399#67399) two days ago on ELL. Here are the questions I asked:

| Date | Question |
| --- | --- |
| December 24th | ["Can I go see my shoes?" vs. "Can I go look at my shoes?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/269832) |
| December 25th | [Why isn't there a way to say "catched up"? We can only say "caught up"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/269922) |
| December 26th | [Is using “pretty damn spicy” to mean “actually very spicy” proper?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/270057) |
| December 27th | [Pronunciation of "Lives"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/270131) |
| December 28th | [Where would I place "at least" in the following sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/270223) |
| December 29th | [Is saying "I am done with my food" proper?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/270354) |
| December 30th | [Why is it that when we say a balloon pops, we say "exploded" not "imploded"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/270483) |

That is seven questions on seven separate days. I read the trigger:

> Each day during a 5-day period, ask a positively scored question and have no negatively scored, closed or deleted questions.

I accomplished that already, and I even have seven. Also two days ago I was awarded the Curious badge on ELL.

Why am I not getting the hat?

I am sure that I didn't delete any questions.

Comment: +1 for using the table feature

Comment: @Eran Haha thanks man :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You did earn it. There was a bug manifesting itself in the trigger-awardHat workflow that was manifesting itself only on ELL that was preventing it from being awarded to you. This has been fixed.

> Edward, oh Edward
> Why did `null` user earn you
> On ELL (sigh)