# Winter Bash 2020 Closing Blog Post Feedback

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

We have just posted out [Ciao Winter Bash 2020!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/05/ciao-winter-bash-2020/) post on the blog where we go over some of the highlights and stats of the event that just ended. Here is an excerpt:

> [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3270037/nick) and [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) earned the very first hats 28 seconds after the event started. The hats (Social Distancing) were earned on Meta Stack Overflow. This year all 17 secret hats were discovered, 11 on the very first day! 3 users ([U11-Forward](https://stackexchange.com/users/11900153/u11-forward), [Panda](https://stackexchange.com/users/6487005/panda), and [double-beep](https://stackexchange.com/users/14688437/double-beep)) earned all secret hats. The most awarded hat, besides Social Distancing, was [Flashlight](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/flashlight). 518,814 unique users earned it 552,178 times total. The rarest hat that we could find on users’ avatars is [Rep Hunter](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/rep-hunter), awarded only to 20 users. If you are one of those who won, congratulations!

Also happy to report that we have more [public stats for WB 2020](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/stats) available on the site.

We are happy to answer below any questions or comments relating to this post (or the event in general).

Comment: Can the triggers for the [secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917/377214) please be fully disclosed? There are still two hats for which we were unable to figure out the triggers, and a few more which weren't fully confirmed by employees.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog We don't generally reveal the solutions to the unsolved triggers as it allows us to use them again in future years.

Comment: @Catija Okay. Can the triggers that are in that post please be confirmed to be correct, if they are, since the post has several unconfirmed triggers? Also, the Vexillologist trigger was partially discovered, so will the full trigger for that be disclosed?

Comment: Just wanna say thank y'all for the far out fun! ;)

Comment: The blog is most informative (telling), and it's twice as long as your question. It doesn't do justice to the timeless efforts, even on days off, that were afforded by our host - even in times of stress, when his steed () faltered, he plowed on. Thanks Yaakov.

Comment: @Yaakov Amazing event!

Comment: any chance of having summer bash this time next year instead, something relevant for the other hemisphere.

Comment: Loved the event, thanks for all the fun! Just wanted to know, who got the last (distinct) hat of the winter bash?

Answer (score 7):

## **Thanks so much for organizing this wonderful event! also making an amazing blog!**

Only a small grammar error.

> The rarest hat that we could find on users’ avatars is Rep Hunter, awarded only to 20 users. If you are one of those who won, congratulations!

I think since WB is over. We should say "was", like:

> The rarest hat that we could find on users’ avatars **was** Rep Hunter, ...

Also in the other part of the sentence, it says:

> , awarded only to 20 users. If you are one of those who won, congratulations!

And mentions "who won", but it might be misunderstood to be "who won the competition". It is supposed to be "who won it". So the full sentence IMO should be:

> The rarest hat that we could find on users’ avatars **was** Rep Hunter, awarded only to 20 users. If you are one of those who won **it**, congratulations!

**Thanks so much for this event!**

Answer (score 5):

I thank you for my five seconds of fame!

I’m glad that Winter Bash 2020 brought people a little fun.

Answer (score 3):

The [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/05/ciao-winter-bash-2020/) wrongly linked "the public stats page" to `/leaderboard`.

```
<p>Enough stats for today! If you want more, there’s a ton of stats on&nbsp;<a href="https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard">the public stats page</a>.</p>
```

Other than that, the post was an enjoyable read. Thanks to the WB2020 team for publishing it so soon!

Comment: Yup congrats for #1