# What is the fate of the Vexillologist hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, secret-hats

Now that Winter Bash 2020 is over, I have a question...

Will the second trigger for the [Vexillologist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917/798831) secret hat be revealed?  It's still listed as "Not figured out yet":

[image]

Now that there is one relatively easy way to earn the hat (I never found the second trigger, I *think*), will the second trigger be officially confirmed?  Or... will the first trigger be scrubbed and the hat will be earned differently in the future?  What is the fate of the Vexillologist hat?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Community Manager @catija more or less answered this already in a comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359237/winter-bash-2020-closing-blog-post-feedback#comment1199133_359237):

> We don't generally reveal the solutions to the unsolved triggers as it allows us to use them again in future years.

Comment: Ah... so will the trigger be used for another secret hat?

Comment: It might be in the future. No guarantees.

Comment: Okay.  I hope so, otherwise the hat wouldn't be secret anymore.

Comment: @Ollie Being secret is less about the solution being generally known and more about whether we advertise in the WB UI what the solution is. Even when we reuse secret hats, they often have the same triggers that were solved in the year the hat appeared originally.